# Trace (or any other form of logs) in deployed (non debug) mobile Flex app

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, logging, mobile, flex4

I'm looking for a way to display log messages in a mobile Flex app.
I know that traces aren't available in non-debug versions, so which alternatives do I have?

What I'd like to do is display this messages in a component, because occasionally I'm getting some weird bugs related to my server connection that don't happen in my office. Just knowing what is going on with the connection would help me debug this issue.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this logging library
[AS3 Commons Logging](http://www.as3commons.org/as3-commons-logging/)

It provides many logging targets, not only the trace one.

Comment: Have you tried the `Logging` API yourself? This might sound stupid right now, but I just can't get it to work and the samples on git aren't complete (`ExampleClass` is missing).

Comment: Yes, I am using this library. It is hard to tell why you can't make it working... All you need to do is to declare a logger "private static const logger: ILogger = getLogger(YourClassName);"

Comment: With ClassName being the class I want to log, or is it a separate class?

Comment: Just a class name you are declaring this logger in. This will allow the logger to display the source of the log info.

Comment: So, lets assume I've got a class named `TestClass` that I want to log. In this class, I create the following constant: `private static const logger:ILogger = getLogger(TextClass);` and whenever I need to log something, `logger.info("some text");` should trace it, correct?

Comment: Yes, correct. Also, please, check this link for more samples how to add additional log targets: http://www.as3commons.org/as3-commons-logging/userguide.html

Comment: Thanks, I've read that several times already, but still can't get it to work. There's nothing displayed in my console.

Comment: Did you add a tracing target?  "LOGGER_FACTORY.setup = new SimpleTargetSetup( new TraceTarget );"

Comment: D'oh! Thanks so much, works like a charm now. Now I can get working on my custom Targets. Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

For a similar problem I've used Monster Debugger

[Have a look here](http://demonsterdebugger.com/)

Comment: Another great answer. Hard to decide between AS3 Commons Logging and Monster Debugger here.

Comment: Ok, dug a little deeper and I don't think Monster Debugger is what I need. Is is more for debugging a device you've got at hand. Instead, I just need to redirect log messages of a deployed application (that is already in the hands of the customer) to a textfield or file so that I can take a look at what has happened with the application.

Comment: I didn't realize your target was mobile

Answer (score 0):

Try `ExternalInterface.call("console.log", "My message")`. It will output "My message" to the browser console. Would it fit your needs?

Comment: Sorry, I need the logs to be displayed inside the mobile app.